# Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu Server 19 connect to hidden WiFi

Tags: pi-4

I'm trying to connect to a hidden access point using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu Server 19.10.

I cannot seem to get it to work. What could be the problem here? Below the output of some of the config.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            optional: true
            dhcp4: true
    # add wifi setup information here ...
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "myAccessPoint":
                    password: "myPass"
            dhcp4: true
```

Seems the wireless interface is enabled, but has no ip:

```
➜  ~ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:58:2b:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.7/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 6725sec preferred_lft 6725sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe58:2b1e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:58:2b:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: UPDATE: got an IP *exactly* after 5 minutes. Is this a router parameter or something I can configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` I've changed `timeout 300;` to `timeout 30;`
and I get an IP a lot faster now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.